# Click tab to change or add css class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is my code:

CSS:

```
.Company-SwitchURL-link{
    color: #b4c7e7;
}
.Company-SwitchURL-link:hover{
    color: #7794cc;
}
.Company-SwitchURL-link.action{
    color: #7794cc;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="Company-SwitchURL-link" id="SwitchURL-company1" data-id="23" data-index="0">Company1</a>
<a href="#" class="Company-SwitchURL-link" id="SwitchURL-company2" data-id="23" data-index="1">Company2</a>
<a href="#" class="Company-SwitchURL-link" id="SwitchURL-company3" data-id="23" data-index="2">Company3</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("click",".Company-SwitchURL-link",function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".Company-SwitchURL-link").addClass("action");
});
```

And when I click the tab "company2" the html element changes to:

```
<a href="#" class="Company-SwitchURL-link action" id="SwitchURL-company2" data-id="23" data-index="1">Company2</a>
```

As you can see, the "action" is dynamic added to the class, but in the website, I cannot see the tab color change.
So, where did I make a mistake where should I update the code?

================================================================

```
$(document).on("click",".Company-SwitchURL-link",function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".Company-SwitchURL-link").removeClass("action");
    $(this).addClass("action");

    id = $(this).data("id");
    index = $(this).data("index");
    view_Company_User(id, index);
});
```

Because my tab element is dynamic to generate to my website in "view_Company_User" function,

so, when I do "view_Company_User" this function to refresh the data in my website,

so that when the action was added to the code,

the website will refresh and then the tab element will return to old code without added action.

Comment: Respected user, there is nothing wrong with the question but when ever you ask the question it would be a nice thing to add a code snippit so that it helps us to find the solution easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The reason why this is happening is because you are adding `.action` to all `<a>`'s
- Instead use `this` to target the clicked `<a>`.
- Also do change the colors as needed.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".Company-SwitchURL-link", function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".Company-SwitchURL-link").removeClass("action");
  $(this).addClass("action");
});
```

```css
.Company-SwitchURL-link {
  color: #b4c7e7;
}

.Company-SwitchURL-link:hover {
  color: #779ee;
}

.action {
  color: #2294bb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="Company-SwitchURL-link" id="SwitchURL-company1" data-id="23" data-index="0">Company1</a>
<a href="#" class="Company-SwitchURL-link" id="SwitchURL-company2" data-id="23" data-index="1">Company2</a>
<a href="#" class="Company-SwitchURL-link" id="SwitchURL-company3" data-id="23" data-index="2">Company3</a>
```

Comment: I try, but still not working, i don't know why

Comment: @ChaChaZhung if you are using browser you can run the above snippet in answer here itself without doing anything and can see that it is working or please explain a little what exactly is not working for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding `action` class to all the nodes with class name `Company-SwitchURL-link` by using `$(".Company-SwitchURL-link").addClass("action");`

If you want to remove the `action` class of other tabs while swtching to a new one use `$(".Company-SwitchURL-link").removeClass("action");` just before adding the new one. This will remove action class from all nodes before adding `action` class to the required node.

Instead you can use the one below.

`event.currentTarget.className += " action";`

**Working Fiddle**

```js
$(document).on("click", ".Company-SwitchURL-link", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".Company-SwitchURL-link").removeClass("action");
  event.currentTarget.className += " action";
});
```

```css
.Company-SwitchURL-link {
  color: #b4c7e7;
}

.Company-SwitchURL-link:hover {
  color: #7794cc;
}

.Company-SwitchURL-link.action {
  color: #7794cc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="Company-SwitchURL-link" id="SwitchURL-company1" data-id="23" data-index="0">Company1</a>
<a href="#" class="Company-SwitchURL-link" id="SwitchURL-company2" data-id="23" data-index="1">Company2</a>
<a href="#" class="Company-SwitchURL-link" id="SwitchURL-company3" data-id="23" data-index="2">Company3</a>
```

Comment: this won't remove `.action` from the previous `<a>` which i think should be ideal behavior.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: event.currentTarget.className += " action"; this cannot working well, nothing change.

Comment: Can you inspect and verify whether the class is getting added in your dom? This is working in the fiddle right?

Comment: @ChaChaZhung if this solved your issue, please approve the answer, happy to have an upvote aswell.

Answer (score 0):

In your click function, edit it:

```
$(document).on("click",".Company-SwitchURL-link",function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".Company-SwitchURL-link").removeClass("action");
  $(this).addClass("action");
});
```